# AWS Create EMR using boto3 Autoscaling not working properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-emr, autoscaling

I am auto scaling emr using **boto3** and then autoscaling it using `EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole`. Autoscaling not working properly:

Initially it gives a warning as

> The policy is pending attachment.

and at last failing giving error as

> The Auto Scaling policy for instance group ig-XXXXXXXXXXXX in Amazon EMR cluster j-XXXXXXXXXXXX (test_emr...) could not attach and failed at 2018-12-19 10:03 UTC.

What can I do to assign the Autoscaling role?

Comment: Reformatted the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to answer by @Harsh Bafna. You also need to set Trust Relationship policy for EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole role.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com",
          "elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the AmazonElasticMapReduceforAutoScalingRole policy to the EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole.

Go to "IAM > Roles > EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole" and in the permissions tab click attach and add the AmazonElasticMapReduceforAutoScalingRole.

Also, to troubleshoot these failures, you can use the describe-cluster command from CLI. The response will include the Auto Scaling policy status, which gives an error message for failure reason if the policy has failed to attach.

Comment: I am not able to find "EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole" role in IAM.

Comment: @GirishJambkar : Can you make sure your user has permission to attach roles to an already running EC2/EMR node. I have also updated the answer with troubleshooting step for actual error.

Comment: @GirishJambkar Welcome. Please accept the answer if it helped you resolve your problem. :-)

Comment: Yes Definitely Harsh!!! It helped me in resolving the issue. In addition to this, we need to set Trust Relationship policy as Ritesh mentioned in reply.